# When building Jenkins in Docker plugins fail to install

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I have a Dockerfile for a custom Jenkins master like so:

```
FROM jenkins
MAINTAINER me

USER root

RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state

RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y sudo \
      && apt-get install -y vim \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER jenkins

# COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
# RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountStartup=100 --handlerCountMax=300"


RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh git:2.6.0
```

Everything works fine until the `RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh git:2.6.0` line. I get an error installing the plugins:

```
Creating initial locks...

Analyzing war...

Downloading plugins...
Downloading plugin: git from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git/2.6.0/git.hpi
Downloading plugin: git-plugin from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git-plugin/2.6.0/git-plugin.hpi
Failed to download plugin: git or git-plugin

WAR bundled plugins:


Installed plugins:
*:

Some plugins failed to download!
Not downloaded: git
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh git:2.6.0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with Jenkins/Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dockerfile works for me, installs all plugins and builds the image successfully:

```
Analyzing war... 
Downloading plugins...
Downloading plugin: git from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git/2.6.0/git.hpi
 > git depends on workflow-scm-step:1.14.2,mailer:1.17,matrix-project:1.7.1,ssh-credentials:1.12,parameterized-trigger:2.4;resolution:=optional,scm-api:1.2,token-macro:1.11;resolution:=optional,promoted-builds:2.27;resolution:=optional,credentials:2.1.4,git-client:1.21.0

Downloading plugin: workflow-scm-step from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/workflow-scm-step/latest/workflow-scm-step.hpi
...
Removing intermediate container 4f895c203944
Successfully built 31d58d1f586f
```

Try `docker build --no-cache` in case there's an issue with one of the layers in your image cache, or set up an [automated build on Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) and build it on Docker's servers.

Comment: Well it worked on Docker Hub, thanks. I wouldn't have thought of trying this. Must be something with my local environment. I'm using docker for mac.

Answer (score 24):

For those who are pulling the jenkins image from dockerHub, dont pull:

```
docker pull jenkins
```

or

```
docker pull jenkinsci/jenkins
```

rather pull the latest version using:

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins
```

This is the latest one according to https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/12/10/the-official-Docker-image/

Comment: As of 04282020 ```docker pull jenkins``` never works as this has been deprecated. I will docker official website would remove this command to save a day for a developer like me.

Comment: Thx, your tip to use the latest jenkins version for docker helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I recall having problems installing with that script myself. Instead, I used the following:

```
RUN install-plugins.sh  \
  disable-failed-job \
  disk-usage \
  greenballs \
  ...
```

And hopefully it doesn't make a difference for this, but I have my plugin install inside of the root portion of my Dockerfile, before dropping back to running commands as `USER jenkins`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be it :-(

Answer (score 0):

The curl timeouts for downloading plugins were insufficient in some cases, that was just fixed for image [2.19.1](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/commit/21b0f37a8b2d4dfa359cfa87eb849531ff5a9290), and it is now configurable too using [`CURL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/2fb0684/install-plugins.sh#L70) and other options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on OS X.

In my case the problem was caused by a bad DNS configuration (obtained by DHCP). When I changed the DNS to Googles DNS 8.8.8.8 it all worked perfectly.

I encountered error messages such as:
Failed to resolve host name "ftp.icm.edu.pl". Perhaps you need to configure HTTP proxy

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and the solution for me was to specify the proxy within the Docker file prior to plugin install. Below is the snippet of my Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins:latest
MAINTAINER Jose Estrada
USER root
ENV JAVA_OPTS="--handlerCountStartup=100 --handlerCountMax=300 --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy-wsa.esl.cisco.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80"
ENV http_proxy <PROXY Settings>
ENV https_proxy <PROXY Settings>
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh cisco-spark-notifier:latest
```

Comment: `jenkins:latest` is deprecated. You should use `jenkins/jenkins:latest`.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

ENV CURL_OPTIONS -sSfLk
ENV JENKINS_OPTS --httpPort=-1
```

Comment: Would have been nice if you shared some context to your answer.
Adding `ENV JENKINS_OPTS --httpPort=-1` Makes the web interface completely unusable. Maybe you had a reason to include this option but without context adding that line broke the web interface.

Answer (score -3):

This could be a DNS issue. Please restart docker daemon and try. (sudo service docker restart)